# Array of struct in C, char**

Tags: c, struct

I was looking forward to make an array of struct just like [ obj, obj, obj ].
I got this struct:

```
struct obj {
    char name[MAX_NAME];
    char desc[MAX_TEXT];
    bool asible;
};
```

How can I make it?

I tried

```
struct obj **objInRoom = malloc(sizeof(struct obj));
```

But when I iterate in it, it doesnt have anything :D
I chose this solution because I need to put that array of struct into this struct:

```
struct room {
    struct obj **objts;     //HERE
    int qntty_objts;
    struct interact **interacts;
    int qntty_interacts;
};
```

Comment: Do you want an array of structs or an array or pointer to the structs? Please show complete code as an [mre] including how you are iterating. But for starters that `malloc` is definitely wrong as the type it is allocating is not compatible with the type it is assigning to. And it is a single element which obviously isn't much of an array. So show complete code to clarify your question.

Comment: You don't need a double pointer; simply malloc enough space for an array of n structures, store n somewhere (presumably qntty_objts) and store a pointer *to the first structure* in a `struct obj *objts` pointer. Incrementing it will move the pointer to the next structure object, indexing it will give you the i-th object. Just like e.g. a pointer of ints.

Comment: I'll try to be short and clear. I have to read a file, this file contains phrases separated in lines, each line contains 3 words like .csv (word;word;false), thats 1 object. So i need to read the file, take each phrase, separate them into 3 words and create an object. With that object I have to create a room, with that structure, can not be modify. Its ok?

Comment: I dont know how to program in C. But my idea was creating an array objects and collect them to create the room. In this case i dont know how to manage that obj**. Cause I dont know why they want that. :')

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have a double pointer for some reason, then you can do something like this `struct obj *objInRoom = malloc(sizeof(struct obj));` and then assign address of `objInRoom` to your struct `room->objts=&objInRoom`.

Answer (score 0):

> `struct obj **objInRoom = malloc(sizeof(struct obj));`

If I simplifies, in your try you are allocating an area for a struct and trying to assign its address to a 'struct obj address' address holder which is `struct obj**`. But you should use `struct obj *` to hold the address of newly allocated area.

Which in this case your struct room should be like this:

```
struct room {
    struct obj *objts;     //struct obj** to struct obj*
    int qntty_objts;
    struct interact **interacts;
    int qntty_interacts;
};
```

You should assign your newly allocated area like this:

```
struct obj *objInRoom = (struct obj*)malloc(sizeof(struct obj));
```

But in this case you only allocated the area for one `struct obj` element. To increase this area you can take the backup of your previous data and allocate new area for more size. For example to increase your allocated area two times:

```
//cap is integer defined before to hold capacity information of array
struct obj *backup = (struct obj*)malloc(2*cap*sizeof(struct obj));
for(int i = 0; i < cap; ++i)
    backup[i] = objInRoom[i];
free(objInRoom); //to prevent memory leak, because we allocated new area for our incremented sized array.
objInRoom = backup;
cap *= 2;
```

Or you can simply use realloc to increase your array capacity if an allocation happened before with malloc or calloc, realloc creates an array with desired size and holds the previous data:

```
objInRoom = (struct obj*)realloc(objInRoom, 2*cap*sizeof(struct obj))
```

**Note:** Always cast your malloc operation to your desired pointer type because it returns 'void *' for default.

**Note 2:** Always check outputs from malloc, realloc and calloc; they return NULL in case of error.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer. The problem here is that I can't modify the structure but some of the solutions there are helping. I think my problem is understanding pointers :/

Comment: @just2anxious If you can’t modify structure you can first allocate area for struct obj** by room->objts = (struct obj**)malloc(sizeof(struct obj*)); and then assign your address of array to this addres by \*(room->objts) = (struct obj*)malloc(cap*sizeof(struct obj));

Comment: The advise to always cast the result is misleading and only adds pointless clutter. Back in C90 it could also cause severe bugs if forgetting to include stdlib.h.